# Access ODBC: JOIN between tables in different database files

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

Let's say I have multiple tables distributed in different Access database files (*.mdb), which I want to combine with a "join" clause into a single dataset. The only solution right now I see is to create linked tables in a Access database, unless someone knows a better and cleaner solution.

Things I have tried are for example creating a SQL statement like `SELECT * FROM tbl_a1 INNER JOIN [file_name].tbl_b1 ON [file_name].tbl_b1.pk=tbl_a1.fk WHERE 1` where "file_name" is not supported.

So I've created a linked table using Microsoft Access, which works fine with `SELECT * FROM tbl_a1 INNER JOIN tbl_b1 ON tbl_b1.pk=tbl_a1.fk WHERE 1`.

What I expect to see a solution to create it programatically, because "machine B" might not have Access installed, and the pre-defined database files do not include linked tables yet. Those tables do not have to be permanent either.
Microsoft has a [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-another-Access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6#bm3) how to create linked tables using only Microsoft Access, but it does not tell me how to do it programatically.

Note: I am using RAD 10 Seattle/VCL C++ Builder with UniDac for database connections by using the ODBC driver, so VBA is not an option.

Solution: In my case I had to set an table alias for the second table `SELECT * FROM tbl_a1 INNER JOIN [C:\path\db.mdb].tbl_b1 AS tbl_b1 ON tbl_b1.pk = tbl_a1.fk WHERE 1` to make it work. Thanks to @Gord Thompson

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can link tables in one 'output' aggregated table in some mdb and then connect your app to this table

Comment: Hello @Nehal, things I have tried are f.e. creating a SQL statement like `SELECT * FROM tbl-a1 INNER JOIN [file_name].tbl-b1 ON [file_name].tbl-b1.pk=tbl-a1.fk WHERE 1` where "file_name" is not supported. So I've created a linked table using Microsoft Access, which works fine with `SELECT * FROM tbl-a1 INNER JOIN tbl-b1 ON tbl-b1.pk=tbl-a1.fk WHERE 1`. What I expect to see a solution to create it programatically, because "machine B" might not have Access installed, and the pre-defined database files do not include linked tables yet. Those tables do not have to be permanent either.

Comment: Is your application using the actual Microsoft Access ODBC Driver or OLEDB Provider to access the database(s)?

Comment: @Gord Thompson ODBC driver

Comment: @E.Kurt, instead of adding things you tried in comments, kindly edit your question and add it there itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach using `[mdbFileSpec].[tableName]` should work if you are using Microsoft's own Access ODBC driver. I can't test this in your C++ environment, but I can confirm that using Python and pyodbc this does *not* work ...

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc

connStr = (
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
    r"DBQ=C:\Users\Public\test\a1.mdb;"
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
sql = """\
SELECT *
FROM tbl-a1
INNER JOIN
[C:\\Users\\Public\\test\\b1.mdb].tbl-b1
    ON [C:\\Users\\Public\\test\\b1.mdb].tbl-b1.pk=tbl-a1.fk
WHERE 1
"""
crsr = cnxn.execute(sql)
for row in crsr:
    print(row)
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

... but this works fine:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc

connStr = (
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
    r"DBQ=C:\Users\Public\test\a1.mdb;"
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)    
sql = """\
SELECT *
FROM [tbl-a1] AS tbl_a1
INNER JOIN
[C:\\Users\\Public\\test\\b1.mdb].[tbl-b1] AS tbl_b1
    ON tbl_b1.pk=tbl_a1.fk
WHERE 1
"""
crsr = cnxn.execute(sql)
for row in crsr:
    print(row)
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Note that

1. I only used the file spec once and created table aliases to refer to the tables, and
2. I put square brackets around the table names because they contained hyphens that could be misinterpreted as minus signs.

Comment: this works like a charm, thank you. I had to set a table alias to use it on my `ON` clause. Someone please upvote this answer.